# When should input and return type hints be used in Python?

Tags: python, type-hinting

```
>>> def greeting(name: str) -> str:
...     return 'Hello ' + name
...
>>> greeting("abc")
'Hello abc'
>>> def greeting(name):
...   return 'Hello2 ' + name
...
>>> greeting("abc")
'Hello2 abc'
```

I see no matter whether the input and return types are specified, the code always work. The doc does not explain when types should be used and when types should not be used. Could you anybody explain this clearly?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: Did you read that **note** at the very top of the page you linked to? They are called *hints* for a reason

Comment: Type hints are *hints* and are entirely optional. When you *should* use them is really a matter of opinion

Comment: In other words, you could strictly always use type hints, or never use them, or sometimes use them. Normally, unless you are using a third-party library, type hints will have *no runtime effect*, although that isn't entirely true, since certain standard library features have started to use the annotations as part of the API, e.g. , `dataclasses` or `typing.NamedTuple`...

Answer (score 2):

Python is a dynamically typed language, and a such the *hints* that you are placing are simply to make it easier for people to understand what types to use when calling that function. The code will work either way. In *statically* typed languages you have to specify the types, and if you put in a value with any other type, the function will **not** work.

Comment: Although note, there are third-party static type checkers for Python, the semi-offical one being `mypy`

Answer (score 1):

Briefly, you should specify type on input or output in case of using that provided/returned variables in your code and would like to have all of the methods what that included type has:

```
def greeting(name: str) -> str:
    return 'Hello ' + name

_str = greeting('you')
```

_str variable will provide you all of the methods when you type **_str.** by your Idea, as well as when you add dot to **name.**

Type aliases are useful for simplifying complex type signatures.
This is useful in helping catch logical errors:

Please, don't be too strict about explanation, I tried to explain by human words)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Vova's answer, because of Python's nature, the interpreter does not require the mention of parameter or return types.
Despite this, it is always a good practice to add type hints, whether as hints or in a docstring, so other developers as well as future you, could easily understand and change the code if needed